# € symbol not showing even when UTF8

Tags: html, character-encoding

For some reason the € is not showing even though this is my header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

[Here is the address](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/demo-table2/)

And what's weird is that the table is loaded via ajax from this address:
[where there's no problem with the characters](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/demo-table2/all-events.html)

Does anybody know why? Thanks :)

Comment: Well, what encoding are you saving the € symbol in on the backend, in source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're saving your text in Latin-1 encoding on the backend. Switching to Latin-1 for your AJAX site displays it correctly. Save your source in UTF-8.

Comment: I clicked on your link and chose different encodings from the browser's View > Encoding menu.

Comment: Ah, right. I was thinking you did it with a console technique.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the page's encoding to Latin-1 (or it's equivalent) be more expedient than translating it to UTF-8? (Note, I'm not well versed on character encoding.)

Comment: Sure, that's another alternative, but you're limiting yourself to the 256 characters encodable by Latin-1, or you have to use cumbersome HTML entities for everything else. This decision may come back to bite you one day.

Comment: You're right (UTF-8 has saved me before). It would depend on the project, though, and it's requirements. If there's a ton of stored content and there's only one or two problems, and little impact from future content anticipated, just changing the page's character-encoding might be preferable to converting.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip! However I am confused as to what you mean by saving my source in UTF-8 on the back-end. In Cpanel, the encoding for index.html is UF8 and it doesn't work. all-events.html is Windows 1252 and it works, however when I change the encoding to UTF8 it doesn't. Then, when I change it back to windows 1252 it still doesn't work and I have to delete the file and re-upload it. :/

Comment: I don't know, it depends on your text editor. In most editors you can choose which encoding to save the file in.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem being that I use jQuery load function which kills all of the encoding. I must post another question, thank you! :)))